# How to CSS two vertical cylinders

Tags: html, css

I want to do this

[image: CSS Cylinders]

How to do these with CSS?

**Update**

How do I align the cylinders on the same bottom, and how do I add the caption below them?

Comment: Can CSS3 be used? What browsers must be supported?

Comment: It should support as much as it is possible.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then I'm sure one of the answers already here will work fine. I was thinking about `border-radius` to make the curve at the top, and CSS3 linear gradients.

Comment: Regarding your update, you should leave a comment on the answer you're using to get the answerer to come back and take another look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to split the cylinder image in three parts: The top, the middle (which will be repeated), and the bottom. Like this:
[image]

Call them top.png, middle.png, and bottom.png, for example.

Then you need three HTML elements, one for each part:

```
<div class="cylinder top"></div>
<div class="cylinder middle" style="height:300px"></div>
<div class="cylinder bottom"></div>
```

And the css:

```
.cylinder {
    width: <width of the cylinder image>px;
}
.cylinder.top {
    background-image:url('top.png') no-repeat;
    height: <height of the top image>px;
}
.cylinder.middle {
    background-image:url('middle.png') repeat-y; /* repeat vertically */
}
.cylinder.bottom {
    background-image:url('bottom.png') no-repeat;
    height: <height of the bottom image>px;
}
```

To change the height or the cylinder, you just have to modify `the style="height:300px"` on the middle element.

This solution will work in any browser, even IE6.

Comment: That was indeed what I meant. +1 for posting the full css.

Comment: However...how about the semantics of the data? Why not transform a TABLE instead of DIVs?

Comment: Maybe I am not calculating right, but if a div is drawn from top top bottom and I need two or three cilinders near each other to be compared, than they would all be aligned at the top and not the bottom if I change the height of the middle, to be able to compare them they all have to be the same height and shortened by a white overlay at the top where is the case.Or am I thinking wrong.

Comment: How do I align the cylinders on the same bottom, and how do I add the caption below them?

Comment: Simpler solution is to use a table: `<table><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom"> (cylinder 1 code here) </td><td style="vertical-align:bottom"> (cylinder 2 code here) </td></tr><tr><td> caption1 </td><td> caption2 </td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/04/16-usable-css-graph-and-bar-chart-tutorials-and-techniques/) is a list of tutorials for the same

You can build one using a [jQuery](http://maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/) plugin as well

or you can try [Google Chart Api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/msvbg/pen/Lymko

This is just for fun. In pure CSS3, no JS or images. A better approach would probably be to simply use one of the many charting libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bottom image for the rounding.
Create a 1px high image for the pipe
Create a little image for the top.

Divide your image into different divs.

```
<div> 
    <div class="bar1">
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can style this with absolute positioning and repeating background images. I don't think it is very easy to do with floating and all, because you have to work from bottom to top.

Comment: How do I align the cylinders on the same bottom, and how do I add the caption below them?

Comment: @Pentium10 By setting the same top position for both bottom classes?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with pure CSS might be overkill. Of course you can use gradients, but you can't get that shadow on the bottom of cylinders with css only. I'm not sure how to do cylinders top with css either.

The easiest way to do that is to use good old background images.

You might consider using `canvas` if you don't want any images at all.

**UPD:** If you can use CSS3, you might wanna use [multiple background images](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/). That way you'll have only one `<div>` instead of three of them. Good semantics.

Comment: -1: pure CSS would not be overkill since the document size becomes much much smaller with css. Therefore not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: So, how can you do that circle shadow on the bottom with pure css and without any image?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://icant.co.uk/csscharts/. It's easily customizable with your own styles and has a handy PHP script for generating the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it can be done with some "brute force".

First of all you should cut the bases of the cilinders and put them on a background of a div with bottom alignment.
then in another div with know and fixed height add two divs of same width that float left and have on the background,repeating on Y axis a slice of a cilinder. then control their height as you need it. Below the div that contains the other two you can add the captions.
Now you will have the cilinders of the same height. In order to "shorten" one you create another div inside it that has a certain height and a white background (repeating image or color).
ex {

```
<div id="chart"> <!-- this one has the bottom cut backgound -->

    <div style="height:200px">

         <!-- cilinder class has the background -->
         <div class="clinder" style="height:100%">&nbsp;</div>

         <div class="clinder" style="height:100%">

              <!-- this one has white bg -->
              <div class="shorter" style="height:30px">&nbsp;</div>

         <div>
    </div>
  <div class="labels">
     <div class="caption">
        Indoor
     </div>
     <div class="caption">
         Outdoor
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should work like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make cylinders with CSS3 by giving it a box-radius.

For example:

```
box-radius: 100px / 30px;
```

This will give you a box an oval look.

Just give it the desired width and height and it's done :)

Or use *jqPlot* as a jquery plugin. This plugin can make lots of graphs.